# Redirect from add_menu_page

Tags: wordpress

I have added a menu using add_menu_page which all works correctly, but when clicked I want this menu page to open the post editor for a particular post id.

As a proof of concept i have tried echoing a javascript redirect out into the do function like so...

```
// Load up the menu page
 function register_availability_custom_menu_page() {
   add_menu_page('custom menu title', 'Availability', 'add_users', 'options',             'options_do_page');
}

function options_do_page() {
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "window.location = '/whatever_page.php';";
echo "</script>";
}
```

This approach does work but I was wondering if it is the best approach, is there a better way to redirect to the page I am after?

### UPDATE

I have now also tried using wp_redirect with this code...

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'admin_menu_new_items' );

function admin_menu_new_items() {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

This gives me a Headers already sent error, can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: I would really like to know too! I am working on exactly this. I have been trying different approaches than you have but to no avail. I was trying 
[[$action = 'edit';
$_GET['post'] = 7;
include('post.php'); ]] which almost works except the widgets don't display and the "screen options" tabs are missing at the top.

Comment: I've got a pretty good handle on it. I now have the sidebar displaying in the custom post editor. I am currently packaging this in a plugin. Do you think this would be useful for people to have? I'll post a full answer as to how to after I thoroughly test it out.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you don't need the redirect. Instead of using a `$menu_slug` in the function [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page), put the address of the target page, e.g.:

```
$the_post_title = 'The Portfolio';

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_59050_add_menu' );

function wpse_59050_add_menu() 
{
    global $the_post_title;
    $our_page = get_page_by_title( $the_post_title );

    $settings_page = add_menu_page( 
        'Edit '.$our_page->post_title, 
        'Edit '.$our_page->post_title, 
        'add_users', 
        '/post.php?post='.$our_page->ID.'&action=edit', 
        '', 
        '', 
        2
    );
}
```

This function is from the following WordPress Answer: [**Highlighting a Menu Item by Post Name**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/59050/12615). You'll need some jQuery to do the correct highlighting of this top level menu, check both my and TheDeadMedic answers in that Q.

This other one is useful too: [**Add highlighting to new Admin Dashboard Menu Item**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/58567/12615).

Answer (score 1):

Recently did this for [pootle page builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pootle-page-builder/), and this AFAIK is the best way,

```
/**
 * Redirecting from Page Builder > Add New page
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
function add_new() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'admin.php' == $pagenow && 'page_builder_add' == filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'page' ) ) {
        header( 'Location: ' . admin_url( 'whatever-page.php' ) );
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_new' );
```

Replace `page_builder_add` with your page slug and `admin_url( 'whatever-page.php' )` with url you wanna redirect to.

We always use scrutinizer-ci for best code practices and maintain code score greater than 9.5/10, so all code (Including this) is secure and optimized ;)

Lemme know how it works for ya.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found a 2-step solution that doesn't use JS/JQ.

**Step 1:**
Near the top of your script, put the following PHP to display CSS that hides your first page:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_my_first_page');

function hide_my_first_page(){
    echo '<style>
        a[href="admin.php?page=admin_menu_slug"] + ul > li.wp-first-item{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

Where `admin_menu_slug` is the 4th argument passed to `add_menu_page();`.

**Step 2:**
Take the function of the page you want to run and pass it as the 5th argument in `add_menu_page();`