# add_menu_page() add_submenu_page() | passing a $variable with called function

Tags: wordpress

I have added a menu page on my WordPress backend with some submenu items.
A snippet of the code i use is:

```
// Add to admin_menu function
add_menu_page(__('New Menu'), __('New Menu Title'), 'edit_themes', 'new_menu_item', 'functiontocallonclick', '', 3.5);
// Add to secondlevel menu
add_submenu_page('new_menu_item', __('New |Sub Menu item'), __('New Menu Title item'), 'edit_themes', 'new_menu_sub_item', 'subfunctiontocallonclick',');
```

As you can see above it is calling the function functiontocallonclick when you go to the New menu item in the backend.

What i am wondering now:
I would like to pass a variable with the function.

```
functiontocallonclick($value);
```

Ofcourse it can't be done that way, so what is the good way?

I use this:

```
switch($_GET['page']){
    case 'suppliers': $type='c';
        break;
    case 'contractors': $type='s';
        break;
    default: $type='';
        break;
}
```

but I try to find some better solution.

Comment: did you find a nice solution?

Comment: Only I change this functiontocallonclick($value) into functiontocallonclick($value='') and $_GET['page'] parametar 'suppliers' into 'c' and 'contractors' into 's'.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might seem late but I'll share how I work around this because it looks like quite a few people are looking for an answer to this question.

My answer is going to be passing variables to a nested function within a class-based context so if you're using functional programming then disregard the $this.

---

The Main hook action:

```
function mainSetup(){
   add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'mainMenuSetup'));
   add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'subMenuSetup'));
}
```

---

Menu Setup:

```
function mainMenuSetup(){
        add_menu_page('DashBoard',
                    'DashBoard',
                    'manage_options',
                    '[yoursitesname]-admin-menu',
                    function(){ $this->pageSelect("admin"); },
                    '',
                    200
                    );  
}
```

Within the example of the Main menu navigation option, we are passed a string in the nested function that will be passed as an argument to the method(function) 'pageSelect', but the string is hardcoded and can't be changed easily. We'll address this problem when setting up the submenu(s).

TODO: You should replace [yoursitename].

---

SubMenu Setup:

For the submenu let's say we want to make it easier to go back and add new submenus and change who has access to which submenus. For this, I'm going to make an associative array called 'subMenuObjects' where the array's keys are the submenu objects and their values are the page's permissions.

```
function subMenuSetup(){

    $subMenuObjects = array(
                    'Settings' => 'manage_options',
                    'Services' => 'manage_options'
    );


    foreach ($subMenuObjects as $subMenu => $value) {

        add_submenu_page('[yoursitesname]-admin-menu',
            $subMenu . 'Page',
            $subMenu,
            $value, 
            '[yoursitesname]' . strtolower($subMenu) . '-menu', 
            function() use ($subMenu){ $this->pageSelect($subMenu); }
        );
    }
}
```

Here we use the 'use' to pass the $subMenu to the nested function.

---

Page select:

```
function pageSelect($page){
    
        switch ($page) {
            case 'admin':
                echo '<div>Welcome to the Admin page</div>';
                break;
            case 'Settings':
                echo '<div>Welcome to the Settings page</div>';
                break;
            case 'Services':
                echo '<div>Welcome to the Service page</div>';
                break;
            
            default:
                echo '<div>something happened, contact dev</div>';
                break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the way you're doing it is the way WordPress does it itself. To re-use admin screens, you have to pass some query var in the URL and then show/hide elements based on that.

You can also create invisible admin screens: [How to enable additional page in WordPress custom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18933965). And this may be useful too: [Redirect from add_menu_page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11419028)