# How to enable additional page in WordPress custom plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a custom WordPress plugin that is showing me a list of data from database. I am registering it's page via:

```
add_menu_page( 
    'Naročila', 
    'Vsa naročila', 
    'administrator', 
    'listaj-narocila', 
    array( &$this, 'listaj_narocila' )
);
```

And then of course I have function `lista_narocila` which is showing me my data.
So, currently my URL is:

```
http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=listaj-narocila
```

And I show my data from database in a table. Now I have button DELETE and EDIT for each record, but I have a hard time figuring it out, how to register custom "url" or "custom page" inside WordPress that would allow me to have URL:

```
http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=single-narocilo?id=X
```

I know I can try with add_menu_page but I *don't* want this page to be in admin menus. Just to be available as URL. Currently I get no access error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sub menu page and [pass `null` as its parent](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Parameters):

> **$parent_slug**
>   Use NULL or set to 'options.php' if you want to create a page that doesn't appear in any menu.

A demo:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() 
{
    # Main page
    add_menu_page( 
        'Vsa', 
        'Vsa', 
        'add_users', // Capability, not role
        'listaj-narocila', 
        function(){ 
            printf(
                '<h2>%s</h2><a href="%s">%s</a>',
                __( 'Main page' ),
                admin_url( 'admin.php?page=single-norcilo&id='.rand(1,25) ),
                __( 'Hidden sub page' )
            );
        },
        'http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico'
    );  

    # Child page    
    $hook = add_submenu_page(
        null,
        'Norcilo',
        'Norcilo',
        'add_users',
        'single-norcilo',
        function(){ 
            printf(
                '<h2>%s</h2><a href="%s">%s</a>',
                __( 'Hidden sub page' ),
                admin_url( 'admin.php?page=listaj-narocila' ),
                __( 'back' )
            );
        }
    );

    # Enqueue script in submenu page to fix the current menu indicator
    add_action( "admin_footer-$hook", function()
    {
        echo <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#toplevel_page_listaj-narocila')
        .removeClass('wp-not-current-submenu')
        .addClass('current');
});     
</script>
HTML;

    });
});
```

<sub>*An alternative approach: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114818/12615*</sub>