# WP Plugin Menu hides when visiting an invisible sub-menu

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin for Wordpress.

There I have the following menu structure:

- Plugin-Name

  - Plugin sub-page
  - Plugin sub-page
  - Plugin sub-page

    - invisible Plugin sub-page

To create the invisible plugin sub-page I used this code:

```
//plugin sub-page
add_submenu_page( 'plugin-main-page', 'Plugin sub-page', 'Plugin sub-page', 'manage_options', 'plugin-sub-page', array(&$this->sub-page, 'showContent') );

//invisible plugin sub-page
add_submenu_page( 
      'plugin-sub-page'
    , 'My Custom Submenu Page' 
    , 'My Custom Submenu Page'
    , 'manage_options'
    , 'my-custom-submenu-page'
    , array(&$this->custom-sub-page, 'showContent')
);
```

Everything works. But:

When I use the link

```
<a href='?page=my-custom-submenu-page'>
```

at the 'plugin sub-page' **the main plugin-menu hides**.

Is it possible that the 'plugin sub-page' is still highlighted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable additional page in WordPress custom plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933965/how-to-enable-additional-page-in-wordpress-custom-plugin)

Comment: The answer I'd provide is exactly the same. You gotta use jQuery for that. Make sure you're only running your code in the plugin's submenu page.