# I want to add a new wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

Happy new year to everyone. I added a new link in my wordpress. The url is `wp-admin/users.php?page=business&user_id=2` but when I access the page is says `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` I know that the page is not created yet **business** How will I create new page so that I can work on `page=business`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page while making a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399252/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-while-making-a-plugin)

Comment: Let me see if it works for me @Milap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really that easy please add the following code. Let me know if you require more help.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'adminMenus');

function adminMenus(){
    add_submenu_page( 'users.php', 'Business Page Title', 'My Business Menu', 'manage_options', 'business', 'businessPageFunction');
}

function businessPageFunction(){
    echo "Meow...";
}
```

For more information View [Function Reference/add submenu page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and [Plugin API/Action Reference/admin menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu)

Comment: Thankyou so much. Can you explain it a little bit please? I want to understand the flow because i'm totally new at wordpress.

Comment: What if I don't want the link to appear in the left menu under users?

Comment: Yeah, as of wordpress we need not to hook "menu pages like add_submenu_page, add theme page..e.t.c" before admin_menu. It is it's structure. [admin menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu)

Comment: Oh God wordpress is so difficult :D

Comment: Hey! no man it is really very very easy, you will love it once you started going deeper ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99450/discussion-between-ali-zia-and-vijaynaidu).

Comment: Please add "null" for menu title and parent slug i.e use the code `add_submenu_page( null, 'Business Page Title', null, 'manage_options', 'business', 'businessPageFunction');` if you don't want the link to appear in the left menu under users